# Getting puppet error on docker ubuntu image

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, docker, puppet, supervisord

I am using `phusion/baseimage` for my ubuntu and i have provisioning done via puppet.

IN the process i get this error

> Error: /Stage[main]/Supervisor/Service[supervisord]: Could not
>   evaluate: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

I searched internet and there are many threads like

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/imtWQNZ3aWo

https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/10955/issues-with-ubuntu-docker-image-and-puppetlabs-mysql/

They all say to use `ubuntu-upstart` as base image.

I want to know that is there any work around which i can do in phusion/baseimage which i can do to fix that issue.

I tried ubuntu-upstart as well but then that image dont have any private keys which vagrant is asking me.

I can log in via conatiner. Is there any thing i can do while logging inside conatiner so that can run that pupper again

```
Vagrant File
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.cmd     = ["/sbin/my_init", "--enable-insecure-key"]
    d.image   = "phusion/baseimage"
    d.has_ssh = true
  end

  config.ssh.username = "root"
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "phusion.key"
end
```

THis is the docker image
https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker

Comment: You raise a question with several tools mix together, can you focus the problem on Puppet only, if you think that's puppet code issue? So with that, you need paste the puppet code which may related with this error, and show us the command you run to get this error, or anything can help to understand your problem.

Comment: @BMW The problem is not related to puppet directly. Its related to docker image of ubuntu where puppet needs upstart to run properly but thats not available in docker image of ubuntu. IN order to solve there is separate image called `ubuntu-upstart` but i dont want to change my image. I wanted to fix that in current version of docker ubuntu

Comment: Ok, if you think that' Docker issue, then show detail on docker setting, such as the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @BMW As i am using vagarnt to create docker image , i have added that file in questions